# UISegementedControl with divider image contains space

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using background and divider images to customize a `UISegmentedControl`. However, a space appears between the divider image and the background image for the segment control.

Here's a screenshot showing the spaces

[image]

And here is the code I'm using to set the segment images

```
UIImage *selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_selectround.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)];
UIImage *unselectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_unselectround.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)];
UIImage *leftSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_leftselected.png"];
UIImage *rightSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_rightselected.png"];
UIImage *neitherSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_bothunselected.png"];

[segment setBackgroundImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segment setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segment setDividerImage:leftSelected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segment setDividerImage:rightSelected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segment setDividerImage:neitherSelected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I checked all the divider images, and they are all the same widths and do not contain any transparent pixels.

How do I remove these spaces from the segmented control?

Comment: Could you add a little bit more on your implementation details? Are you using UIAppearanceProxy, subclassing it?

Comment: @Rexeisen I added the code I am using to set the background images

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the images you use for the dividers (`leftSelected`, `rightselected`, and `neitherselected`) are all the same width. Often because `neitherselected` has the line in the middle it's 1pt wider than the others. They all need to be the same!